# NSUndoManager and replacing/skipping undo steps

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsundomanager

Is there any way to tell `undoManager` that in some case the undo step has already been committed before the edit has happened?

I have an application which automatically replaces certain strings with uppercase counterparts. Trouble is, this has to be done automatically into `textStorage`, so when undoing the edits, text remains uppercase.

I've already written custom undo states for the operations in question, which are created in `NSTextView shouldChangeTextInRange`:

For example:

```
[[self.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] 
       replaceCharactersInRange:
             NSMakeRange(affectedCharRange.location + affectedCharRange.length, string.length + 1) withString:string
];
```

I'd like the `undoManager` to ignore the undo step it's going to receive after the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is disabling `NSUndoManager` from logging undo steps by using `[self.undoManager disableUndoRegistration];`. Then, after the operation is done, you can enable it again with `[self.undoManager enableUndoRegistration]`.

This seems to be a bit dangerous approach because it can really mess up you undo stack.

I fixed this issue by making an extra undo step before the `NSTextView` undo gets registered:

```
[self.undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self handler:^(id _Nonnull target) {
    [self replaceCharactersInRange:undoStringRange withString:undoString];
}];
```

Redoing can cause harm here, though, because the whole affected string might not get registered with text view's internal methods.